# eCharts: How to remove Japanese character in download button when canvas is rendered

Tags: canvas, echarts

I did some research before but dont get any luck, im trying to remove those japanese characters.

[image]

I looked over all options but no luck so far

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Echarts supports custom `toolbox feature title` option to change that characters in

```
toolbox.feature.saveAsImage
```

for example:

```
option = {
    toolbox: {
        show: true,
        feature: {
            saveAsImage: {
                title: 'save As Image'
            },
            restore: {
                title: 'restore'
            }
        }
    },
    ...
    title: {},
    xAxis: [],
    ..
}
```

BTW, it's not Japanese characters, it's Chinese characters.
'保存为图片' means 'save as image'